# Upload CSV file in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo

I have to upload CSV file with this format in Bank Statement module in odoo 12 :

```
Ref;Debit;Credit
ref1;;89,000
ref2;2,380;
ref3;2,380;0,500
```

My problem is how to add condition if a field : credit or debit of the file is empty and to remplace it with "0.0" to calculate the amount .

My code in odoo 12:

```
def My_funct(self):
Reader = csv.DictReader(base64.b64decode(self.file_name).decode('utf-8').split('\n'), delimiter=';')
for row in reversed(list(Reader)):
      self.env['account.bank.statement.line'].create({
               'ref': row['Référence'],
               'amount': float(row['Crédit']) - float(row['Débit']),

                    })
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition like:

---

```
credit = 0.0
if row['Credit'] != None:
    credit = row['credit']
```

---

And use above credit variable in your vals of bank statement line create.

Regards,
Mustufa Rangwala (Probuse)